# Adding elements to a list

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, list

I have a list of some elements.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Assume the list contains values as below:

```
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

How do I add a dummy element (E.g. -1) as a separator before each of the group? he result should be

```
-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,2,2,2,2,2,-1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,-1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

How do I do that efficiently?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Comment: What is the main idea behind this request that you are going to do, may be there is an alternative and better solution

Comment: I don't think you'll do better than a brute force iteration through the list, for the simple reason that you need to compare every pair of consecutive elements.  So you can't ever do better than O(n).

Comment: @BasselKh There may be. But its just the part of my problem. After sorting the list. I want to group it so that I can use it for the solution.

Comment: Unless it really needs to be done in this way (is it homework ?), it shouldn't be done at all. A typical way of dealing with this kind of situation would be to keep a map from values to their number of occurrences, and if you ever actually need to print them in this way, iterate through the map and build the output as you go.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Look into my updated answer, is that what you are searching for. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Method 1:**

By overriding the **[add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)** function.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(){
    public boolean add(Integer add){
    if(super.size()==0 || super.get(super.size()-1)!=add)
        super.add(-1);
    super.add(add);
    return true;
    }
};
```

Now `list.add(number);` will override the add function and adds another integer (ie-1), whenever it finds a change in value from the last element.

**Method 2**

In the traditional way. Iterate Over and add `-1` when a change is found.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4));  
        int last=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i)!=last){
                last=list.get(i);
                list.add(i, -1);
                ++i;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of the previous values and iterate through the list.

```
List<Integer> origList = getListHowever();
List<Integer> spacedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int bufferElement = -1;
int currVal;
int lastVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  // or some default value that is unlikely to be in the list

for (int i=0; i<origList.size(); i++) {
    currVal = origList.get(i);
    if (lastVal != currVal) {
        spacedList.add(bufferElement);
    }
    spacedList.add(currVal);
    lastVal = currVal;
}
```

The same methodology could be followed as items are added to the original list. Either keep track of the last value added or peek at the last element.

Comment: Please use a `int curVal = origList.get(i);` and refer to that, you now do `origList.get(i)` 3 times in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linked hash map, do for loop over the array, put the number as key and frequency as value.
NO need to put separators at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know the value and the number of element in each group, you can use two arrays. For example, if you have n different distinct values (or n group) , you can have an array `int[] value` and `int[]count` with `value[i]` is the value of the ith group and `count[i]` is the number of element in the ith group.

So in your case :

```
int [] value = new int[5];
int [] count = new int[5];
value[0] = 0;
count[0] = 5;
value[1] = 1;
count[1] = 4;
......
```

To convert from the `list` to `value` and `count`, you just need to do two binary search for finding start and end indexes of a specific value in the `list` (if `list` is sorted). So the time complexity will be O(nlog m) with m is the size of `list`.

As Zoyd mentions in his comment, we also can use `HashMap <Integer,Integer>` to store the value and number of element pair, or `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` to maintain their sorted orders.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, in case repeating integers are sorted.

Sorted repeating integers example:

```
0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4
```

**Code**

```
class FrequencyOrderedSet
{
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> list;

    public FrequencySet()
    {
        list = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> ();
    }

    public void insert (Integer number)
    {
        if (list.constainsKey(number))
            list.put(number, list.get(number)+1);
        else
            list.put(number, 1);
    }

    public void remove (Integer number)
    {
        if (list.containsKey(number))
            if (list.get(number) > 1)
                list.put(number, list.get(number)-1);
            else
                list.remove(number);
    }

    public ArrayList getList ()
    {
        ArrayList out = new ArrayList<Integer> ();

        for (Integer num : list.getKeyList())
            for (int i=0; i<list.get(num); i++)
                out.add(num);
    }
}
```